# php функция preg_replace

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Доброго времени суток.

У меня есть самая простая строка:

```
i3g=on
```

C помощью функции **preg_replace** я хочу из этой строки взять только цифру "3" и поместить её в переменную, без замены.

Comment: @MedvedevDev и что же по вашему будет в `$num` ?

Comment: @teran, в теории массив

Comment: @teran, true :D. Надо указать третий аргумент, т.е. массив с результатом.

Comment: @MedvedevDev _["preg_match() возвращает 1, если параметр pattern соответствует переданному параметру subject, 0 если нет, или FALSE в случае ошибки. "](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php)_ вы где ваши теории черпаете?

Comment: Да, извиняюсь, давно с php не сталкивался. preg_match('/\d+/' , 'i3g=on', $matches); print_r($matches);

Comment: @teran, свои теории беру из остатков памяти.

Comment: @MedvedevDev от этого  исправления `$num` не станет содержать искомые данные

Comment: @teran, проще было наверное самому написать, чем меня поправлять?

Comment: @MedvedevDev большое спасибо, я почему-то зациклился, по неопытности, именно на "preg_replace" функции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ очень прост. Вариант с preg_match():

```
<?php

$str = 'i3g=on';
preg_match('~\d+~', $str , $a);

echo join($a);
```

Так же можно и с помощью preg_replace():

```
<?php

$str = 'i3g=on';

echo preg_replace('~\D+~', '', $str);
```